# Jsoup getElementsByClass returns null value

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to write a program that fetches prices information from a certain site. I want to get the first element, but the getElementsByClass returns a null value.

```
 String site = new String("https://www.ebay.it/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=" + searches[n] +"vhs&_sacat=0&_sop=15");
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(site).header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0").timeout(600000).get();
                elements = document.getElementsByClass("s-item__price").first();
                prices[n] = elements.text();
```

This code is in a thread that gets launched when I press a button. This is the button listener

```
       findPrices.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            searches= new String[1000];
            for (int t = 0; t < numeroEdit+1; t++) {
                searches[t] = new String();
                searches[t] = String.valueOf(editTexts[t].getText());
                searches[t].replace(' ', '+');
            }
                Thread t1 = new Thread();
                t1.start();
                ll.removeAllViews();
                ll.addView(addLine);
                ll.addView(findPrices);
                for(int l =0; l < numeroEdit; l++){
                    editTexts[l].setText(prices[l] + "l");
                    ll.addView(editTexts[l]);
                    editTexts[l].setText(prices[l]);
                }
            }

    });
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I visit the page. There is no such class `s-item__price`. I find this class `hl-item__price`.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking to the link in your example shows no usefull information, because searches[n] is not explained. In this form a valid answer is not possible. Please refine your example.